# How do I install Haystack without CUDA?

Tags: python, django, docker, haystack

I have integrated the Haystack vector search library into my Django application, and now I'm going through and attempting to turn the project into a Docker container.

Everything is working okay, but I have noticed that when I build my Docker container, a lot of time is being spent on downloading and installing NVIDIA CUDA python packages.  I am not deploying my containers on a platform with GPUs, and so I would like to install Haystack without installing the CUDA python packages.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of cuda packages is caused by the torch dependency installed as an extra of the transformers dependency. You can find it in [Haystack's pyproject.toml file](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/6774e0ae583d2f88169d2dfb069ef9a84ca69052/pyproject.toml#L51).

What you can do to prevent that is to install torch with the following command. There is no CPU version of PyTorch on PyPI (tracked by [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/26340)) which is why we need to provide an index-url in the command:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```